# How to match custom Fails with the failure crate

Tags: error-handling, rust

I'm trying to understand how to use the [failure](https://docs.rs/crate/failure/0.1.5) crate. It works splendidly as a unification of different types of standard errors, but when creating custom errors (`Fails`), I do not understand how to match for custom errors. For example:

```
use failure::{Fail, Error};

#[derive(Debug, Fail)]
pub enum Badness {
  #[fail(display = "Ze badness")]
  Level(String)
}

pub fn do_badly() -> Result<(), Error> {
  Err(Badness::Level("much".to_owned()).into())
}

#[test]
pub fn get_badness() {
  match do_badly() {
    Err(Badness::Level(level)) => panic!("{:?} badness!", level),
    _ => (),
  };
}
```

fails with

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> barsa-nagios-forwarder/src/main.rs:74:9
   |
73 |   match do_badly() {
   |         ---------- this match expression has type `failure::Error`
74 |     Err(Badness::Level(level)) => panic!("{:?} badness!", level),
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `failure::Error`, found enum `Badness`
   |
   = note: expected type `failure::Error`
              found type `Badness`
```

How can I formulate a pattern which matches a specific custom error?

Comment: Not really familiar with the library, but you may need to downcast the contained error, [this](https://docs.rs/failure/0.1.5/failure/struct.Error.html#method.downcast) seems to be the method for that.

Comment: Unfortunately, there seems to be no `failure` on the playground, but [this](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=27b1c1d144efd4dfed5b6c72c0a9a8d2) compiles locally. (not the best way to do this, though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## You need to downcast the `Error`

When you create a `failure::Error` from some type that implements the `Fail` trait (via `from` or `into`, as you do), you temporarily hide the information about the type you're wrapping from the compiler. It doesn't know that `Error` is a `Badness` - because it can also be any other `Fail` type, that's the point. You need to remind the compiler of this, the action is called downcasting. The `failure::Error` has three methods for this: `downcast`, `downcast_ref` and `downcast_mut`. After you've downcast it, you can pattern match on the result as normal - but you need to take into account the possibility that downcasting itself may fail (if you try to downcast to a wrong type).

Here's how it'd look with `downcast`:

```
pub fn get_badness() {
    if let Err(wrapped_error) = do_badly() {
        if let Ok(bad) = wrapped_error.downcast::<Badness>() {
            panic!("{:?} badness!", bad);
        }
    }
}
```

(two `if let`s can be combined in this case).

This quickly gets very unpleasant if more than one error type needs to be tested, since `downcast` consumes the `failure::Error` it was called on (so you can't try another `downcast` on the same variable if the first one fails). I sadly couldn't figure out an elegant way to do this. Here's a variant one shouldn't really use (`panic!` in `map` is questionable, and doing anything else there would be plenty awkward, and I don't even want to think about more cases than two):

```
#[derive(Debug, Fail)]
pub enum JustSoSo {
    #[fail(display = "meh")]
    Average,
}

pub fn get_badness() {
    if let Err(wrapped_error) = do_badly() {
        let e = wrapped_error.downcast::<Badness>()
            .map(|bad| panic!("{:?} badness!", bad))
            .or_else(|original| original.downcast::<JustSoSo>());
        if let Ok(so) = e {
            println!("{}", so);
        }
    }
}
```

`or_else` chain should work OK if you actually want to produce some value of the same type from all of the possible\relevant errors. Consider also using non-consuming methods if a reference to the original error is fine for you, as this would allow you to just make a series of `if let` blocks , one for each `downcast` attempt.

## An alternative

Don't put your errors into `failure::Error`, put them in a custom enum as variants. It's more boilerplate, but you get painless pattern matching, which the compiler also will be able to check for sanity. If you choose to do this, I'd recommend `derive_more` crate which is capable of deriving `From` for such enums; `snafu` looks very interesting as well, but I have yet to try it. In its most basic form this approach looks like this:

```
pub enum SomeError {
    Bad(Badness),
    NotTooBad(JustSoSo),
}

pub fn do_badly_alt() -> Result<(), SomeError> {
    Err(SomeError::Bad(Badness::Level("much".to_owned())))
}

pub fn get_badness_alt() {
    if let Err(wrapper) = do_badly_alt() {
        match wrapper {
            SomeError::Bad(bad) => panic!("{:?} badness!", bad),
            SomeError::NotTooBad(so) => println!("{}", so),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *Don't put your errors into `failure::Error`, put them in a custom enum as variants.* — This is actually a big point of my [SNAFU crate](https://crates.io/crates/snafu), which enhances standard Rust enums for error handling.